# How to know if transaction scope was successful or not

Tags: c#

I need to know if my transaction scope was successful or not. As in if the records were able to be saved in the Database or not.

Note: I am having this scope in the Service layer, and I do not wish to include a Try-Catch block.

```
bool txExecuted;

using (var tx = new TransactionScope())
{
   //code
   // 1 SAVING RECORDS IN DB
   // 2 SAVING RECORDS IN DB

   tx.Complete();
   txExecuted = true;
}

if (txExecuted ) {

   // SAVED SUCCESSFULLY
} else {
  // NOT SAVED. FAILED
}
```

Comment: Are you using standard ADO.NET and SQL server?

Comment: dotnet core and sql server

Answer (score 1):

The commented code will be doing updates, and will probably be implemented using ExecuteNonQuery() - this returns an int of the number of rows affected. Keep track of all the return values to know how many rows were affected.

The transaction as a whole will either succeed or experience an exception when it completes. If no exception is encountered, the transaction was successful. If an exception occurs, some part of the transaction failed; none of it took place

By considering these two facts (records affected count, transaction exception or no) you can know if the save worked and how many rows were affected

I didn't quite understand the purpose of txExecuted- if an exception occurs it will never be set and the if will never be considered. The only code that will thus run is the stuff inside if(true). I don't see how you can decide to not use a try/catch and hope to do anything useful with a system that is geared to throw an exception if something goes wrong; you saying you don't want to catch exceptions isn't going to stop them happening and affecting the control flow of your program

Answer (score 0):

To be clear, calling the [Complete()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.transactions.transactionscope.complete?view=netframework-4.8#System_Transactions_TransactionScope_Complete) method is **only an indication** that all operations within the scope are completed successfully.

> However, you should also note that calling this method does not
>   guarantee a commit of the transaction. It is merely a way of informing
>   the transaction manager of your status. After calling this method, you
>   can no longer access the ambient transaction via the Current property,
>   and trying to do so results in an exception being thrown.
>
> The actual work of commit between the resources manager happens at the
>   End Using statement if the TransactionScope object created the
>   transaction.

Since you are using ADO.NET, [ExecuteNonQuery](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executenonquery?view=netcore-2.2) will return the number of rows affected. You can do a database lookup **after** the commit and **outside** of the using block.

In my opinion, its a mistake not to have a try/catch. You want to catch the [TransactionAbortedException](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.transactions.transactionabortedexception?view=netcore-2.2) log the exception.

```
try
{
    using (var scope = new TransactionScope())
    {
        using (var conn = new SqlConnection("connection string"))
        {

        }

        // The Complete method commits the transaction. If an exception has been thrown,
        // Complete is not  called and the transaction is rolled back.
        scope.Complete();
    }
}
catch (TransactionAbortedException ex)
{
    // log
}
```